# How to use different offset for each duplicate created with array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to generate several copies of an object, but place them at specific locations. One way I thought I could do that was to use the array modifier, but have it use different relative offset for each iteration (eg. the first clone is created with relative offset {1, 0, 0}, second with offset {0, 1, 0} and third again with offset {1, 0, 0} to create sort of S shape).

I tried to use the array modifier multiple times on one object with different offsets, but it always duplicated all the objects previously created by previous array modifiers instead of creating just one new copy.

I understood that using array modifier is probably not the way to go. How could I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can use duplication (*instancing*) on the faces of a different mesh

1. Create a mesh, with one face per each intended duplication location

   [image]
2. Select the object to duplicate, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *Select* the newly created mesh. Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, then *Parent to Object*.

   [image]
3. (optional) make the origins of the two meshes coincide
4. On the "S" shaped mesh, under *Duplication* in the *Object* panel, choose <kbd>Faces</kbd>

   [image]

(btw, the "S" mesh won't be rendered: only your object's instances)

[image]

Comment: Although I don't precisely understand why it works, it does. Thanks for answer!

Comment: *Duplication > Faces* (once called "duplifaces", soon to be called "instancing on faces") means just that: on each of the (Parent) object faces, create an instance of the Child object. You can also duplicate on vertices, but I personally think that faces give you more control, as you can rotate them in the 3D space and make it affect the instances.

Comment: I had no idea this was even a feature. +1!

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way to accomplish what you need is to create a Bezier curve wich have te route that you want, then add a array modifier to the mesh that you wish to duplicate but set the Fit Type to "Fit curve", finally you can add a Curve modifier and in the Object, select the curve. So the first modifier will match the curve's length and the second will match the route that you need.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't do what I wanted. I want the original mesh undisturbed, but just place copies of it at arbitrary places. So I want to have the same mesh at some specific locations I set.

Comment: Sorry man, the other thing that comes to mi mind is that you use Alt + D to duplicate and link objects so when you modify one it affect all of them. I hope this actually helps.